# ReactJS add anchors in sidebar for post titles

Tags: reactjs, markdown

I have a problem not solved yet:
A page allow users to create post (editor is markdown format). In detail of this post, we have a sidebar which contains anchors for post title h1, h2, h3 link to correspondence position of titles.

How to do that? Please support or give me a keywords :<
Thank you !

Comment: "React markdown"? https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown I mean... I think you should do your research first. You seem to already know what you need which is markdown.

Comment: Sorry @IamL, I used react-markdown and allowed user create post. So, I am finding how to print heading titles in the post, list them on the sidebar, when users click a specific title, user will go to this title position ?

Comment: Sorry buty I have no idea what you mean, maybe you can provide a snippet / codepen for this?

Comment: Dear @IamL, image that: I have content mardown user typed. So in detail post, I have UI: Main (left) is content, Sidebar (right) is table of content (heading title) of post

Comment: I can bind markdown content to screen (main, left) but I have not found how to get that table of content :< ?